# Elasticsearch - find the minimum and maximum values for each characteristic

Tags: elasticsearch

I have data in this format.

First data:

```
"properties" : [
  {
    "char_id" : 347,
    "char_value_string" : "107",
    "char_value_int" : 107
  },
  {
    "char_id" : 906,
    "char_value_string" : "8",
    "char_value_int" : 8
  },
  {
    "char_id" : 908,
    "char_value_string" : "Question_V1",
    "char_value_int" : null
  }
}
```

Second data:

```
"properties" : [
  {
    "char_id" : 347,
    "char_value_string" : "110",
    "char_value_int" : 110
  },
  {
    "char_id" : 906,
    "char_value_string" : "18",
    "char_value_int" : 18
  },
  {
    "char_id" : 908,
    "char_value_string" : "Question_V2",
    "char_value_int" : null
  }
}
```

Third data:

```
"properties" : [
  {
    "char_id" : 347,
    "char_value_string" : "220",
    "char_value_int" : 220
  },
  {
    "char_id" : 906,
    "char_value_string" : "54",
    "char_value_int" : 54
  },
  {
    "char_id" : 908,
    "char_value_string" : "Question_V3",
    "char_value_int" : null
  }
}
```

I need to find using aggregation the maximum and minimum values of `char_value_int` for each `char_id`. My request does not work:

```
GET products/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "properties": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "properties"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "char_ids": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "properties.char_id",
            "size": 10000
          },
          "min_char_values_int": {
            "min": {
              "field": "properties.char_value_int"
            }
          },
          "max_char_values_int": {
            "max": {
              "field": "properties.char_value_int"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on info that you provided, it seems that you don't have any nested information, so you don't need a nested aggregation.

A simple aggregation in aggregation will work for your case.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "char_ids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "properties.char_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "min_char_values_int": {
          "min": {
            "field": "properties.char_value_int"
          }
        },
        "max_char_values_int": {
          "max": {
            "field": "properties.char_value_int"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

returns

```
 "aggregations": {
    "char_ids": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 347,
          "doc_count": 3,
          "min_char_values_int": {
            "value": 8
          },
          "max_char_values_int": {
            "value": 220
          }
        },
        {
          "key": 906,
          "doc_count": 3,
          "min_char_values_int": {
            "value": 8
          },
          "max_char_values_int": {
            "value": 220
          }
        },
        {
          "key": 908,
          "doc_count": 3,
          "min_char_values_int": {
            "value": 8
          },
          "max_char_values_int": {
            "value": 220
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: But I have a problem: if value of filed `char_value_int` is equal float `18.5`, then the maximum value rounds it to an integer `18`.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58080162/elasticsearch-rounding-numbers-by-functions-min-and-max