# Elasticsearch - Rounding numbers by functions min and max

Tags: elasticsearch

I have data in this format.

First data:

```
"properties" : [
  {
    "char_id" : 347,
    "char_value_string" : "107",
    "char_value_int" : 107
  },
  {
    "char_id" : 906,
    "char_value_string" : "8.5",
    "char_value_int" : 8.5
  },
  {
    "char_id" : 908,
    "char_value_string" : "Question_V1",
    "char_value_int" : null
  }
```

}

Second data:

```
"properties" : [
  {
    "char_id" : 347,
    "char_value_string" : "110",
    "char_value_int" : 110
  },
  {
    "char_id" : 906,
    "char_value_string" : "18",
    "char_value_int" : 18
  },
  {
    "char_id" : 908,
    "char_value_string" : "Question_V2",
    "char_value_int" : null
  }
}
```

Third data:

```
"properties" : [
  {
    "char_id" : 347,
    "char_value_string" : "220",
    "char_value_int" : 220
  },
  {
    "char_id" : 906,
    "char_value_string" : "54",
    "char_value_int" : 54
  },
  {
    "char_id" : 908,
    "char_value_string" : "Question_V3",
    "char_value_int" : null
  }
}
```

I use aggregation to find the minimum and maximum value of `char_value_int` for each `char_id`. This aggregation works but if `char_value_int` is float, then this max or min is rounded to integer (as example, `8.5` is rounded to `8`). I need to get exactly `8.5`, not `8`.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "char_ids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "properties.char_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "min_char_values_int": {
          "min": {
            "field": "properties.char_value_int"
          }
        },
        "max_char_values_int": {
          "max": {
            "field": "properties.char_value_int"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the mapping of the field `char_value_int`? If it's an integer then 8.5 is stored as 8, which is normal.

Comment: "char_value_int" : {  "type" : "long"  }

Comment: Yeah, that's the reason. Your value is stored as a long integer, hence the decimal part is gone at indexing time... even though it says 8.5 in your source document. You need to change your mapping and reindex your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your value is stored as a long integer, hence the decimal part is gone at indexing time... even though it says 8.5 in your source document.

You need to change your mapping to `float` instead and reindex your data.

Then you're going to get the expected min/max values